# Rails - escaping SQL params

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, sql-injection

I am doing some plain SQLs in my rails model (for purists this is just for complex SQLs :)

Since I am not using find*/condition methods, is there a helper method that I can use straight to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`quote`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#M001483) method on the connection object escapes strings. When building up queries, use [`sanitize_sql_for_conditions`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize_sql_for_conditions) to convert ActiveRecord conditions hashes or arrays to SQL WHERE clauses.

The methods in [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::DatabaseStatements`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html) are handy for direct queries, in particular the ones starting with `select_`.

Comment: yes in my model I am doing connection.select_all(sql). But I cant find the "quote" method on connection object in rdoc for escaping my input params for where conditions.

Comment: `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` seems to be moved to a module and set to private.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses [`sanitize_sql_for_conditions`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_conditions) internally for dealing with placeholders. Of course, that method is protected so you can't (cleanly) use it outside of an ActiveRecord model. You can get around the protectedness using [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
escaped_string = Model.send(:sanitize_sql_for_conditions, [
        'id = ? and name = ?',
        params[:id], params[:name]
    ]
)
```